# Magento 2: How to call Widget programatically?

Tags: layout, theme, widget, magento-2.1.4

I have created widget

```
Type: CMS Static Block
Theme: My Theme
Display on: All Pages
Container: CMS Footer Links
Template: CMS Static Block Default Template
Widget Options: Block (My selected block)
```

It display my block content on Footer.

Above settings work fine in default Magento 2.1.4 CE, but it's not working on my Porto Theme.

So how to manually call my Widget in my Theme i think Theme's default.xml or in .phtml file or in My Custom Module?

Answer (score -1):

You can created the Widget in Block in admin panel and use in the .phtml file using below code:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a block called `header_tel` then inside of a `.phtml` file, you can programatically display the block using this:

```
<?php
    echo $block->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block') // Static block
          ->setBlockId('header_tel') // id of block
          ->toHtml(); // render block
?>
```